Encryption & Decryption in Jmeter
We have recorded a script for a web application. but in request body & response body I can see the data is Encrypted. Now to do this script work for multiple users we need to write a encryption decryption logic. We checked with developer they provided us logic which is Javascript as below.
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
const DECRYPT_SECRET = "Your_Secret_Key";
 
 function encryptQuery(val) {
  //console.log("val00--", val);
  const encJson = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
    JSON.stringify(val),
    DECRYPT_SECRET
  ).toString();
 
  const encData = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(
    CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(encJson)
  );
 
  return encData;
}
 
 function decryptPostResponse(val) {
  // console.log("val00--", val);
  const decData = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(val)?.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
 
  const bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(decData, DECRYPT_SECRET)?.toString(
    CryptoJS.enc.Utf8
  );
 
  return JSON.parse(bytes);
}
let val = {
    "userName": "Test1",
    "password": "Test@12345",
    "userType": "user"
}
 
let encrypt = encryptQuery(val)
 
console.log("-- ",encrypt)
 
let decrypt = decryptPostResponse(encrypt)
console.log(decrypt)

Can anyone help me to covert this code in groovy? I tried in chatgpt as well but that code is not working.
I need groovy code which will work in Jmeter.

SO is not a code delivery service. Please post your most recent Groovy code (preferably with test data) and describe the problem.

As an exception I provide a proof of concept, but I don't think it's correct to ask the community to do your job for your because this is something you're getting paid for. If you're stuck with something, i.e. your code doesn't work as you expect - provide a minimal reproducible example and let us know the expected behaviour
In the meantime I can only suggest getting familiarized with the following materials:

Encryption and decryption with Groovy
Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?



Why provide an image of code instead of properly formatted code text?
